Optimisations flags activated by gcc -O0 are not all disabled
I'm a computer science student and for a project I have to study different C compilers and see what optimization flags are enabled at which level of optimization.
So with gcc, I have the command gcc -Q --help=optimizers -O0 | grep enabled which displays me all the flags enabled by gcc -O0, the problem is that there are a lot of flags such as -fpeephole and -faggressive-loop-optimizations.
There shouldn't be any optimization at this level, so that's quite strange.
Do you have any idea of why is it ?
I'm on Fedora Workstation 40 and gcc is version 14.2.1 20240912 (Red Hat 14.2.1-3).

See the linked duplicates.  Also note that many -f optimization options do nothing unless some optimization level other than -O0 is enabled.  The ones that are on by default even at -O0 might still actually work, or some might not and it's easier to manage the GCC source code to have them on by default, only turned off by -Os / -Oz.  But GCC does by default do stuff like turning x / 10 into a multiply+shift with a magic constant instead of using slow idiv, even at -O0.  See Basile's answer on the first duplicate I linked.

(At first I thought I was going to write an answer, then I noticed how well the existing Q&A I knew about answered what you were asking.  But if you feel like there's still an unanswered question here, you could [edit] to focus on that and we could potentially reopen if there aren't existing duplicates for other aspects.  It's a good question, just one that's already been asked and answered in a slightly different form.)
